# can php error_log place in remote network location in windows environment

Tags: php, windows, iis, error-log

We are running php 5.5 fast CGI mode in Windows 2008 server with IIS.
Currently our php error log is residing inside C:\PHP\ folder. We have windows enterprise domain environment. But growing the size of error_log file became a real problem to the server space and performance. I was thinking the solution for this issue, We have to move error_log file into separate windows server location within the domain or limit the log file by log rotating.

Can anyone give me a advice to configure log rotation limit to maximum file size? or
configure php error_log place in remote network location in windows environment

Comment: since it's windoze, you could just have `error_log = \\server\share\file`. Just make sure the share and underlying directories/files have appropriate permissions.

Comment: I already tried to do that, I gave appropriate permission to the file too. But error logging was not working afterwards. Couldn't figure it out.